# How can I heal my villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm using [MineColony](https://sites.google.com/site/minecolony/) to get some useful NPCs.  When they first spawned, their bars overhead all said `20 hp`, but now, most are down to `10 hp` or less.

I don't want my workers to die.  How can I get their health back up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just throw splash potions of instant health, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the only NPCs that heal in the mod are [Guards](http://minecolony.wikkii.com/wiki/Guard), who heal themselves by eating food.

Employing guards should keep hostile mobs off your other villagers, so that they shouldn't need healing anyway!

Comment: Um, according to the wiki, guards aren't implemented yet.  Is this wrong?  But regardless of whether guards are here or not, it's still impossible to heal anyone else?

Comment: @JohntheGreen As far as I can tell, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.minecolonies.com/publicforum/m/18051739/viewthread/10537296-lumberjack-searching-for-trees-bug/post/last#last) from one of the developers:

> Regarding regen health.. I thought they healed themselves for 5 hp each night... If you always skip the night cycle though you will miss this

Considering I like to sleep a lot in the early game, this is probably my problem.

Answer (score -1):

so far in 1.7.10 your villagers will heal over time at 1hp per maybe around 3 seconds